# Laravel 5.3 routes one url 2 controllers middleware

Tags: php, laravel-routing, laravel-5.3, laravel-authorization

I am trying to use a differt controller for authorized users(middleware auth) and guests(middleware guest) with the same URI but I can't get it to work in laravel 5.3.

I tried making 2 routes with the same URI and differt middleware, but it isn't possible to create 2 routes with the same URI.

I tried a lot of things but in laravel 5.3 I can't use `Auth::check()` in the routes file, it will always return false:

```
Route::get('/', [
    'as' => 'home', 
    'uses' => (Auth::check() ? 'User\DashboardController' : 'Guest\HomeController'),
]);
```

I also tried to use a function in the route:

```
Route::get('/', [
    'as' => 'home', 
    'uses' => function (){
        $app = app();
        if(Auth::check()){
            $controller = $app->make('App\Http\Controllers\User\DashboardController'); 
            return $controller->callAction('getIndex', $parameters = []);
        }else{
            $controller = $app->make('App\Http\Controllers\Guest\HomeController');
            return $controller->callAction('getIndex', $parameters = []);
        }
    }
]);
```

Now the `Auth::check()` does mostly work, but now the middleware in the controllers `__construct` function gets ignored. And this doesn't look very nice.

I also have the problem when I redirect from the login to this route `Auth::check()` returns false. But if I refresh the page it returns true.

I do not want to use 1 controller and handle both the user and the guest in that controller, this is because my user controller extends another class than my guest controller.

Does someone know how I can have 1 route with a controller for guests and a differt controller for authorized users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create new middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class isGuest
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (! \Auth::check()) {
            return redirect('/guest-page');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Then you need to register the new middleware in the app/Http/Kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
];
```

And then just attach it to the needed routes:

```
    Route::get('user', [
        'uses' => 'UsersController@index',
        'as' => 'users.index'
    ])->middleware('isGuest');
```

You can also use several middleware for one route:

```
  Route::get('user', [
        'uses' => 'UsersController@index',
        'as' => 'users.index'
    ])->middleware('isGuest', 'secondMiddleware' ...);
```

More information here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware#global-middleware

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't explain how I can have 2 controller on one URI...

Comment: @JanWytze You cannot. You're not supposed to put logic in route definitions. Use a middleware as Roman suggested.